# Can't convert string to DateTime in c#

Tags: c#, string, date, datetime

Now I know this question get's asked a lot, but I keep running into the same problem with every solution I try. I am trying to convert a string in format "yyyy-MM-dd" to type DateTime, but I keep getting the following error:

`Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.String'.`

The property is the following:
`public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }`

The line where I'm trying is something as follows: `DateOfBirth = //Conversion happens here\\`

What I have tried:

```
DateOfBirth = DateTime.ParseExact(reader.GetString(6), "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
DateOfBirth = DateTime.ParseExact(reader.GetString(6), "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateOfBirth = DateTime.ParseExact(reader.GetString(6), "yyyy-MM-dd", null);
Convert.ToDateTime("reader.GetString(6)")
```

Just nothing seems to work. It's propably something really stupid I'm overlooking, but I just can't seem to find the issue. Hope you guys can help?

Greetings,
Jacob

Comment: and what `reader.GetValue(6).GetType()` returns? ... I bet "System.DataTime" ... so it cannot be obtained with `GetString`

Comment: I can not replicate your issue with this following code: `DateTime test = DateTime.ParseExact("2019-11-21", "yyyy-MM-dd", null);` it works as expected. Check that `reader.GetString(6)` actually returns the expected value.

Comment: The format of the string representation must match a specified format exactly or an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading your error, your actual problem is that you're trying to convert a DateTime to a string, as you say:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.String'.

This isn't a problem with you converting the string to a date time, but a problem with the reader converting the datetime to a string. This is what you should be looking into. I'm unsure on what the type of your reader is, so maybe look at the docs for a 'GetDatetime' method attached to the reader. Or create one, or tell us the type of the Reader and we'll see.

Comment: Yes, this is true. I thought that was really weird, but I didn't know my reader class had a GetDateTime() method. It is fixed now.

Comment: No problem, easily done, just make sure you read your error and then you can actually search for the error, rather than thinking it's something else.

Answer (score 3):

My god, I know it was something really stupid. I needed to use `reader.GetDateTime()`.

I am so terribly sorry for this stupid question. I have been busy with this problem for a few hours now and just when you ask a question, you fix it. Welcome to software development I guess...

Answer (score 0):

First, check what `reader.GetString(6)` returns?

Comment: maybe `reader.GetString(6)` throws this exception ... question is not clear

Comment: That returns the type string.

Comment: And what is the contents of that string?